# How to download Google Analytics data for my web domain automatically

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-api

I have a web domain on which I use Google Analytics to track users. I want to be able to download a report for my domain automatically (by a server running a scheduled job) via a web API every day.

I have looked at the Google Developers documentation to try to find out how to do this, but I couldn't find a simple step-by-step guide for this particular use case.

Is anyone able to either a) outline the steps required to achieve this, or b) point me to an existing step-by-step guide?

What I have done already:

1. Create a Google Developers service account.
2. Added the email address of the service account to the list of users who can access the analytics data for my domain.

as described [here](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/). However, that page then goes on to use tokens and embed graphs. I just want a simple script to download data via a single http request (if possible).

The [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) is also useful.